# Better Autocomplete for the Front-End

Tags: front-end, functions

I wonder if it is possible to improve the front-end's autocomplete capability. Compared with some other more sophisticated editors/IDEs, such as eclipse, Mathematica's front-end does not provide a good autocomplete capability.

The front-end provides an autocomplete feature through `(Control|Command)[+Shift]+K` key bindings. But it has several different shortcomings. First off, the key binding is not the easiest one to use. I really prefer `Control+Space` or `tab` key combination which is used in many other editors rather than the Mathematica's unique `Control+K`. However, one can [modify the key binding](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~jeremy/mathematica/keybindings/) to his own choice.

Second, the function/variable name autocomplete feature, shows a list of options just over the line that you are typing rather than underneath the line. So, you cannot see what you have already typed in:

[image: Mathematica's AC]

Compare it with eclipse:

[image: eclipse AC]

Another nice feature of eclipse, that Mathematica supports a simpler version of through `Control+Shift+K`, is the parameter suggestion feature. Once you choose a function/class name from the above list, it shows you another list with all possible function/constructor parameters, which makes the life much more easier.

[image: Parameter Completion]

Eclipse even provides camel case notation:

[image: Camel Case]

Is that possible to modify the Mathematica's front-end to support such capabilities?

*Note:* Here is a list of Mathematica functions/options that might be useful:
`NotebookEventActions`,
`NotebookSelection`,
`CurrentValue`,
`Names`.

Comment: Under windows MMA 8.0.0, XPx64 I'm seing the dropdown list properly below what I'm typing. however, not in W7x64 MMA 8.0.4

Comment: The above screenshot is for MMA 8.0 under Mac OS 10.7.4.

Comment: It's 8.0.1.0, Mac OS X x86(32-bit, 64-bit Kernel).

Comment: The FE does completion by calling the kernel function `FE``FC`.  Which is a very simple and naive function.  Rewriting it could be the basis for an answer here.  That having been said, this is radically revamped in v9 (coming soon!), and I wouldn't recommend any answer based upon this notion be applied to v9.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16599/is-it-possible-to-improve-mathematicas-auto-completion-feature

Answer (score 10):

Since version 9, autocomplete [behaves](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/UseTheInputAssistant.html) the way it does in modern IDEs,

[image]

including links to the documentation (the little document button), <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete, and additional information available through a drop-down after completion:

[image]

See the following questions for information on writing templates for your own functions:

- [Template completion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15378/37)
- [Multiple templates for a single user-defined function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19816/5)

Comment: `Since version 9, autocomplete behaves the way it does in modern IDEs` except for one big shortcoming [how-to-keep-the-ctrlshiftk-help-menu-remain-in-display-while-typing](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29538/how-to-keep-the-ctrlshiftk-help-menu-remain-in-display-while-typing) (and there is no answer to this as of version 10.01)

Comment: @Nasser: Yes, that's annoying (though I bet some IDEs play that way too).