# Template completion

Tags: front-end, bugs, keyboard, version-9, autocomplete

In version 8, if one evaluates

```
test::usage="test[x,y]";
```

then types `test`, then <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> (or <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>), a template appears with placeholders for `x` and `y`.

In version 9, this does not work: if I evaluate the same thing, when I type `te`, I am offered the choice to select `test` from the dropdown menu, just like for the built-in functions. If I select `test` and then press <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>, however, I do not get the template (whereas I do get a template for built-in functions if I do this).

How do I get the frontend to show a template?

## Note: This has been fixed as of 9.0.1

Comment: Apparently, I was a little heavy handed with the "remove all instances of v.9 tag." Reverting ...

Comment: I haven't downloaded version 9, but my suspicion would be that they now draw their template information from somewhere else, not `test::usage`. Maybe you can poke around to see if there is something like `test::template`? That's only a wild guess - it's what might make sense if this is actually an enhancement and not a bug.

Comment: @Jens that's a good idea. I can't see anything other than the usual `usage` messages, but maybe I am missing something. Let's see if someone else can find something

Comment: It doesn't work for me with version 9 on Win 7, 64-bit.

Comment: I would also like to know how to make my own InputAliases appear on the autocomplete list...

Comment: So this should also be tagged version-9 bug ...right?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch yes I think so. Done!

Comment: I *think* the completion information is stored here:  `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, 
  "SystemFiles/Kernel/TextResources/English/FunctionInformation2.m"}]`.  You will need to `Uncompress` the file after importing it as `String`.  The *actual* usage messages are also in that directory, stored in `Usage.m`.  If you look at most packages, the `::usage` messages are plain text only, but when you load the package, and `?` the symbol, you'll get a nicely formatted usage message with italicized arguments.  This comes from `Usage.m`, not from the package file.

Comment: `FunctionInformation.m` contains syntax colouring info, I think.

Comment: For completeness sake: Related question —  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19816/5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To clarify the situation: In Version 9 on Windows and OS X, there is a new Make Template system which supports multiple templates for built-in functions.  As part of the new system, unfortunately a bug was introduced which makes it ignore the usage statement for user-defined functions. This bug has been confirmed and we hope to fix it in a future release, though I cannot make any prediction as to when. The Linux front-end does not yet feature this new make-template system due to certain technical obstacles, which means it also does not suffer from the new bug.

There also seems to be some confusion as to how to invoke make template in version 9.  Here is how it works: the new code assist offers possible completions as you type instead of forcing you to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>.  Now, if you select a completion from the code assist using <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or left click, you will notice that a small down arrow appears, like so: [image: scerenshot of collapsed completion menu].  This down arrow is the collapsed template list.  And this point, you can activate Make Template either using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>, or by hitting <kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to expand the arrow.  Alternatively, if you've typed in a complete symbol, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> will activate make template even if you haven't selected something from the code assist. Unlike previous version, Make Template does not currently attempt to complete a symbol before opening the template menu.

Comment: It's worth noting that you may specify a popup delay for autocompletion -- so you don't get the popups when you know what function you want but do get them when you're uncertain. Set this on the Mathematica 9 Preferences dialog, Interface tab.

Answer (score 4):

### Partial solution for Linux (Ubuntu 12.04, GNOME 3.4.2)

In version 8 I can expand it into a template the same way that normal expansion works. In version 9 this seems to work differently. You have to expand (or type) the full function name first and press then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

```
xxyyzz::usage = "xxyyzz[x,y]";
```

Now I type

```
xx
```

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I get

```
xxyyzz
```

then I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to do the template expansion. This is still a bug to me though.

Comment: I can get up to he `xxyyzz` part, but after that if I press shift-cmd-k, nothing happens. do you get the `xxyyzz[x, y]` thing? what do you press, the same as in earlier versions? (shift-ctrl-k?)

Comment: @acl After some hours of sleep I tried this again. On Linux-x86-64 this is exactly the way it works.

Comment: OK I see. It would be useful for others on windows and linux to also try; so far it seems that 3 of us find it not working on OS X, 1 found it not working on win8 but could not check in detail, and?

Comment: It would be useful if the people upvoting also wrote a comment saying eg "yes, it works here too with this OS" (if that's why they are upvoting)

Comment: This doesn't work for me on OS X.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Me too, Win 7 x84. I filed a bug report.

Comment: if this bug is confirmed on MMA9, it would be very annoying for me. I get the template working well for my/standard functions in MMA8. I will get MMA9 later today and we will see.