# How to create 'help' `?` for a function (as documentation)

Tags: function-construction, usage-messages

I have defined a function `foo` in some complicated way.  But now I would like to add a little documentation that gives the user information on how it is to be used.

I know that the `?` symbol could be placed before a built-in function to generate useful information about that built-in function.  Is there a way I can add helpful information about my `foo` function in a similar way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can include usage info using the `::usage` tag as follows

```
foo::usage = "foo[x] takes one argument and returns nothing"
```

Using `Information[foo]`  or `?foo` will display the string in the above message

```
?foo
(* "foo[x] takes one argument and returns nothing" *)
```

In addition, in version 8 (and some older versions), using <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> will complete the template if you start the usage message with `foo[x] ...`. Unfortunately, [this doesn't work in version 9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16019/5).

Comment: It is safe to say that *Mathematica*'s `::usage` and template system is best described as "kludgy".  For the benefit of others I provide a link to a question that summarizes the various problems and possible workarounds:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/what-is-the-status-of-usage-and-templates-in-mathematica-v10-1

Comment: How do I change the message in the floating message which appears when the function name is typed?

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way for a short documentation is by adding a usage to a function, as described in the other answer above.

For a more in depth documentation (as in the Mathematica help) you can use Wolfram Workbench, a tutorial can be found there
http://www.wolfram.co.uk/products/workbench/.

Alternatively you can have a look at this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center

Comment: it *might* be the best way, but for sure not the simplest.

Comment: Yes I agree, I modified my answer accordingly.