# Can I create a mouseover summary or documentation for a new function?

Tags: functions, front-end

In *Mathematica*, when you hover any a built-in function, a small window with 2 symbols appears (as in the third paragraph of this [reference page](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/built-in-functions/), see picture): clicking on the former one gives you a quick description of the function ("summary"), whereas the latter is a link to a detailed page on the function ("documentation").

My question is if it's possible to do exactly the same on a function defined by the user.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wolfram.com](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/built-in-functions/images/built-in-nestlist.png))</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Duplicates: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17176/5 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19816/5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by using the [`MessageName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageName.html) operator (`::`). Here is an example.

[image: foo]

Comment: Thank you! What about the creation of document pages? Is it possible?

Comment: @OscarCharles. I believe that is possible with Wolfram Workbench. I have never use that development tool (not installed on my system), so I have no experience with writing Wolfram-like documentation pages.