# Techniques To AutoReplace Browse

Tags: functions, files-and-directories

Let's say I have a function of the form.

```
Test[File_,text_]
```

What would be the most automated way and flexible way to generate an input cell of the form,

[image]

such that when you press the File Button and select `"C:\\Users\\path\\testing.txt"` it autofill with the textual arguments.

[image]

I'm quit interested to see what the Mathematica community thinks is the best technique for specifying which arguments should be File `Button`s and if it might be possible to incorporate the File buttons with [Template Completion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15378/template-completion/15380#15380).  My current code is below, which isn't generalized to all function definitions, but I knew it would be best to attempt to create a partially working solution.  I used the [following question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/how-to-create-a-notebook-element-that-can-replace-itself) to help piece a together my partially working example.

---

```
MakeBoxes[replacementMarker[a_, tag_], StandardForm] ^:= 
  TagBox[MakeBoxes[a], tag];

 replaceMark[rule_, nb_: EvaluationNotebook[], which_: All, 
   cell_: EvaluationCell] := (
   SelectionMove[nb, which, cell]; 
   NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]] /. rule]
   ) ;

CellPrint[
 Cell[
  BoxData[RowBox[{"Test", "[", 
       RowBox[{
          ToBoxes@replacementMarker[
         Button["Browse",
          replaceMark[
           file = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
           TagBox[_, "replaceThis"] :> "\"" <>
             StringReplace[file, "\\" -> "\\\\"]
             <> "\""
           ]
          ], "replaceThis"]
       , ",", 
          TagBox[
            FrameBox["test"],
            "Placeholder"]}], "]"}]]
  , "Output"]
 ]
```

Comment: there is some code here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/resources-for-beautiful-mathematica-stylesheets/14865#14865 in which you press a button and the button is replaced by text. You may be able to hack that around to do what you want for this task.

Comment: I copied your code into the question.  It's not excessively long, and I think it is better to have it here than linked exclusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with something like this:

```
file = Button["File", file = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]];
CellPrint@ExpressionCell[test[Dynamic@file, Placeholder[text]], "Input"]
```