# Multiple templates for a single user-defined function

Tags: function-construction, version-9, documentation

How do I use the `::usage` tag to allow the Mathematica v9 front end to know that there are multiple ways to call an overloaded function (a function that can have different number of arguments?

For example, if I sequentially run the two commands

```
myfunc::usage = "foo[x,y,z] will combine x, y and z for you.";
myfunc::usage = "foo[x,y,z,w] will be even better.";
```

The second line has overwritten the first and the front end doesn't know about both cases.  A built-in example of what I'm talking about is `Table` which the front-end recognizes as having many different templates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of *Mathematica* 9, multiple autocomplete templates are supported and the different templates are delimited by newlines. So for your example, you'll need to define them as:

```
myfunc::usage = "foo[x,y,z] will combine x, y and z for you.

foo[x,y,z,w] will be even better.";
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  But, I am now trying to add a third template, and adding yet another line seems not to work.  Does having three templates work for you?

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes it works, but only if it was defined that way initially. If you want to add a new definition, it looks like you'll have to `Remove` the symbol first (`ClearAll` doesn't suffice, even though the message definitions are cleared). My guess is that since the template completion is handled by the FrontEnd, it loads this when the function is first defined and remembers it forever and is unaware of later changes to the symbol in the kernel.