# Generate a list of all user defined functions including their argument patterns

Tags: documentation, document-creation

I have defined a bunch of functions over several different files, and I would like a list of prototypes of all the functions I have defined in my current session (I want the mathematica equivalent of the .h file for my .c file).

For example, if I defined two functions,

```
f[arg1_, arg2_]:= Module[...];
g[t_]:= Module[...];
```

Then I would want the following list (alphabetized, of course):

```
f[arg1_, arg2_]
g[t_]
```

It would be nice if the list could be exported to a notebook or pdf for quick viewing. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: You are aware that referring to this as "the mathematica equivalent of the .h file for my .c file" is actually a misnomer? Mathematica doesn't need header files.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries C does't need header files either... I could just put prototypes at the top of the .c file. I write header files to give me a clean organized list of all the things that are going to appear in the .c file. It is a coded form of documentation.

Comment: There are conditions where those headers are needed, for instance in functions that mutually reference each other. Not so in Mathematica.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Prototypes are needed for mutually referencing functions. A separate header file is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one solution (that needs a bit of improvement to make it useful):

```
functionList[context_String] := 
 TableForm@Sort[
   HoldForm @@@ Flatten[
      (ToExpression[#, InputForm, DownValues] & /@ Names[context <> "*"])[[All, All, 1]]]]
```

Now just do `` functionList["Global`"] ``.

It does not handle `UpValues`, `SubValues`, `OwnValues`, but most of your *functions* are likely to use `DownValues`.

---

Considering your use case, take a look here too:

- [Multiple templates for a single user-defined function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19816/multiple-templates-for-a-single-user-defined-function)

Writing usage messages is going to be a much better solution.  Simply taking the pattern you used in the function definition (as I did above) might sound like a good idea at first, but it conflicts with some common Mathematica patterns such as [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25150/12).

Comment: This is perfect for my needs!

Comment: Hi, Szabolcs. Thank you for your solution. I would like to know further how to list function within current notebook?

Answer (score 4):

There is something close to what you ask for built into *Mathematica*. It is the function called [`Information`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Information.html). In the form you would use to get what you asked about, there is a keyboard shortcut, the question-mark character.

```
a = 42;
f[arg1_, arg2_] := Module[{}, {arg1, arg2}]
g[t_] := t^2
?"Global`*"
```

[image: glob1.png]

Each of the symbols shown above is actually a button and gives further information about the definition of the symbol when clicked on. For example, were I to click on `f`, I'd get

> f[arg1_, arg2_] := Module[{}, {arg1, arg2}]

The string "Global`*" is interpreted by `Information` as meaning "show me all the symbols defined in the Global context". A context is a *Mathematica* namespace and `Global` is the namespace where user defined symbols go unless you do something special to prevent it.

Note that this works only for symbols that have been evaluated

Comment: This is a cool thing to know, but it doesn't really solve my problem. I really want the arguments included. The reason I'm doing this is so I can remember what arguments all my functions take.

Comment: @nullUser You probably might be interested in defining templates for your functions: [Multiple templates for a single user-defined function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19817)

Comment: But as I said in my answer, if you click on the function name you will see all the definitions you have made including all the argument patterns it accepts.

Answer (score 0):

How's your pattern matching? Mine's not at all good (yet), but you might be able to rustle up some kind of solution using this as a starting point:

```
functionScan[p_] := 
 StringCases[p, 
  result : ( 
     WordCharacter .. ~~ "[" ~~  Except[ "]", _] .. ~~ "]" ~~  _ ~~  
      ":=" ) :> result]

files = FileNames["GraphicalLSystems*.nb"];
result = functionScan[Import[#, "Plaintext"]] &  /@ files
```

with the result:

```
{{"LSystem[0,  axiom_,  _] :=", 
  "LSystem[iterations_,  axiom_,  rule_] :=", 
  "LOGO[commands_,  {startx_,  starty_,  starta_}] :=", 
  "geometry[system_,  iterations_] :=", "thumbnail[system_] :=", 
  "Module[{gosper,  abs,  arg}, gosper[abs_,  arg_,  baseAngle_] :="}, 
  {}, 
  {},
  {}}
```

Formatting the results should be easier!