# How to keep the ctrl+shift+k help menu remain in display while typing?

Tags: notebooks

In Mathematica 9, one can type `ctrl+shift+k` to display menu which has all the possible signatures/definitions for the function or command in question.

One can select one of those, which is pasted in place, Then the menu disappears right after that.

[image]

That is all fine. But what I really prefer, is to have the menu remain in display, while writing the rest, either myself or even if the fill-in was selected.

I like to keep looking at the small menu for reference, since it has information in it that helps while writing the rest of the function call, also, it is possible one might decide to change which one of those signatures to actually use while typing, and it would be easy to do that if the menu is still up there for reference on the other signatures.

What happens now is that once one starts typing, the menu goes away, and one loses the reference that was there to look it.

Is there a way to keep this menu in place while typing, then use some other special key to close it? That would be really useful. i.e. I like something like this:

[image]

**Is there a way to keep this menu up and close it when I choose using another short-cut key?**

Version 9.01 on windows 7.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really a front-end enhancement request that should be directed to Wolfram Research.

Comment: I think what is asked for in this question would be a very useful improvement to the front-end's usability. If implemented, I would like to be something that can be turned on and off by the user.